# Ansible 2.4 when var is defined and contains

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm currently writing a ansible playbook with several conditions.
I have a uri block with a when condition. The when condition checks if the var is defined and contains 0:

```
when: (logs_table_exist.stdout == "0") or ("0" in logs_table_old)
```

Now `logs_table_exist` will always have a value but `logs_table_old` can also be undefined. This when condition gives no error but it stays on false, even if `logs_table_old`is 0.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is any chance your variable might be undefined, use the [`default` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables):

```
when: (logs_table_exist.stdout == "0") or ("0" in (logs_table_old | default([])))
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. turns out i need to put .stdout to the logs_table_old and than it works. ```when: (logs_table_exist.stdout == "0") or ("0" in (logs_table_old.stdout | default([])))```